# What causes frosting when applying a varnish?

Tags: preservation, varnish

Sometimes when applying the final varnish on a miniature, it ends up going opaque / frosting.  What causes this to happen, and how can it be prevented?  I have seen this occur with both Vallejo and Liquitex gloss varnish, while using a brush to apply.

Comment: which brand are you using?

Comment: I have tried both Vallejo and Liquitex and it clouds up about 10% of the time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What system are you using? Airbrush or bottle spray?

- I have experienced a lot of frosting when applying varnish in humid environments.
- I have observed more frosting with spray bottles compared to airbrush (I dilute the varnish for airbrushing with Vallejo airbrush thinner).
- Only apply a very thin layer of varnish at a time. I have observed frosting when I put too much varnish at once, especially with spray bottles. If more is needed, several thin layers may be applied.